# HasManyThrough with one-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on small scale CMS for a project with tables like so:

```
- pages
    - id
    …
- translations
    - page_id
    …
- menus
    - id
    …
- menu_page
    - menu_id
    - page_id
    …
```

In the Menu model I have this relationship:

```
function pages(){
    return $this->hasMany('Page');
}
```

Is it possible to create a relation directly between Menu and Translations that translates to something like this SQL query:

```
select translations.* 
from translations
inner join menu_page on menu_page.page_id = translations.page_id
where menu_page.menu_id = ?;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it with builtin methods, `hasManyThrough` won't work with many-to-many relation menus-pages.

However you can try a workaround like this:

```php
public function getTranslationsAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('translations', $this->relations)) $this->loadTranslations();

    return $this->getRelation('translations');
}

protected function loadTranslations()
{
    $translations = Translation::join('menu_page', 'translations.page_id', '=', 'menu_page.page_id')
        ->where('menu_page.menu_id', $this->getKey())
        ->distinct()
        ->get(['translations.*','menu_id']);

    $hasMany = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany(Translation::query(), $this, 'menu_id', 'id');

    $hasMany->matchMany(array($this), $translations, 'translations');

    return $this;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```php
$menu = Menu::find($id);
$menu->translations; // Eloquent Collection of Translation models
```

So basically just like you would use any relation. The only trouble is that you can't eager load it.