# Eloquent: Get pages based on user role

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `User`, `Role` & `Page` setup, all with many-to-many relationships and the pivot tables setup in the usual fashion (`role_user`, `page_role`), along with the eloquent methods to attach a model to the pivot tables.

My idea is to allow a user to have many roles, and a page can be accessed by many roles.

However now I'd like to return a collection where I have my users details and then the pages they're allowed to access.

The closest I have got is:

```
return User::find( Auth::user()->id )->with('roles.pages')->first()->roles;
```

Now this returns each role the user has, and each page that the role can access. Which is correct, however I have duplication on the `pages` part.

How would I go about getting only a list of pages the user is able to access with no duplication?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read that answer to get you on the track: [HasManyThrough with one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788844/hasmanythrough-with-on-to-many-relationship/23789210#answer-23789210)

Only for your setup you need to adjust the query - join 2 pivot tables (and make sure they represent real data, ie no rows referencing non-existing models):

```
// User model

// accessor so you can access it like any relation: $user->pages;
public function getPagesAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('pages', $this->relations)) $this->loadPages();

    return $this->getRelation('pages');
}

// here you load the pages and set the collection as a relation
protected function loadPages()
{
    $pages = Page::join('page_role as pr', 'pr.page_id', '=', 'pages.id')
           ->join('role_user as ru', 'ru.role_id', '=', 'pr.role_id')
           ->where('ru.user_id', $this->id)
           ->distinct()
           ->get(['pages.*', 'user_id']);

    $hasMany = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany(Page::query(), $this, 'user_id', 'id');

    $hasMany->matchMany(array($this), $pages, 'pages');

    return $this;
}
```

One more thing: I hardcoded tables and columns names for sake of simplicity, but in real life I suggest you rely on the relationships and their getters, like: `$relation->getTable()`, `$relation->getForeignKey()` etc.

---

Now suggestion about your code:

```
return User::find( // 2. query to get the same user
     Auth::user()->id  // 1. query to get the user and his id
   )->with('roles.pages')
     ->first() // 3. query to get ANOTHER user (or the same, luckily..)
     ->roles;
```

1. Use `Auth::id()` instead of `Auth::user()->id` (for Laravel ver 4.1.25+) to avoid redundant query
2. `find()` and `first()` are methods that execute the query, so you just returned the user with id = `Auth::user()->id` and moment later you fetch another one, who comes `first()` from the users table..
3. You don't need to use `User::whatever` for authenticated user, use `Auth::user()` instead.

So the code with suggested solution would look like this:

```
Auth::user()->pages; // collection of Page models with unique entries
```

Comment: Awesome cheers for the heads up, works great :) EDIT: Is it correct to load the `Page` model from inside the `User` model directly?

Comment: What do you mean by correct? Isn't it what you needed :) It is just adjusting what framework offers to match your needs.

Comment: Would it be possible to show me the above how it's properly supposed to be implemented? Also if the user isn't logged in I need to check if there is any pages which have the role "guest". Logic is working in this paste, but doesn't seem the "best" way of doing it... http://laravel.io/bin/QqlnD

Comment: Check the edit, you have everything concerning `User` model there. And here's the paste for you http://laravel.io/bin/mlqzq

Comment: Ahhh I see! Another thing though, surely "User" will never have the relation with pages, so it will always execute the "loadPages()" method?

Comment: Not at all. Check the accessor, last action there: `matchMany` is going to set the relation on `$this`. This is how the relations are attached to the model. You can always play with this and see what queries are run etc. with `artisan tinker` in cli. It is great source to learn how Eloquent works.

Comment: Hey @deczo, any idea how i'd go about getting specific coulmns from the pages table. For example just the name and ID rather than everything (including the timestamps etc)

Comment: I suppose you want to output only certain fields to the user, so check model's `hidden`/`visible` properties. Otherwise simply use `select` on the query