# Has many through self referencing in laravel returns empty set

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel v8 and i have a `products` table to hold a product data, the product will have a child product and i'm connecting it using `product_relations` table.

`products` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PC |
| 2 | Mouse |
| 3 | VGA |

`product_relations` table

| id | parent_product_id | child_product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |

I want to retrieve the child product model using the parent product model, to achieve this I'm trying to use `hasManyThrough` function in class model like this;

```
class Product extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'products';
    public function childs(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(self::class, ProductRelation::class, 'child_product_id', 'id');
    }
}

class ProductRelation extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'product_relations'; 
}
```

then i tried to retrieve it like this:

```
$childs = Product::find(1)->childs()->get();
```

but it returns an empty set of product model

Comment: I take it there is only 2 levels to the relationships i.e. `parent` > `child` and not `parent` > `child` > `grandchild` etc.?

Comment: yes @Rwd only parent > child

Comment: Why not just have a parent_id and a one-to-many relationship? Side note: I would change `childs` to `children`

Comment: @GertB. sadly i don't have the authority to change the db structure

Comment: In that case you are looking for the `belongsToMany` with `product_relations` as the pivot table

Answer (score 2):

1- this kind of relation is not necessary. because parent product and children products have one-to-many relations not many-to-many.

2- hasManyThrough get destination class address not self::class.(like: ChildProduct::class)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a many-to-many with a pivot table:

```
public function childs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'product_relations', 'parent_product_id', 'child_product_id');

    }
```