# laravel hasmanythrough on manytomany

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, many-to-many, has-many-through

I am building an app with a many-to-many between users and roles and a many-to-many between roles and permissions.
I would like to get the permissions of a user with the hasManyThrough, but it doesn't work. This relation expects a user_id in the roles table, but as they are many to many, there is none of course.
Anyone who has a fix?

Answer (score 0):

hasmanythrough on a many-to-many relationship is not possible.

This has been answered in more detail in another thread:
[HasManyThrough with one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788844/hasmanythrough-with-one-to-many-relationship/23789210#23789210)

And you can also refer to: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/i-has-many-through-relation-laravel-the-missed-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

There is a Laravel 5.5 composer package that can perform multi-level relationships (deep)

Package:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Example:

`User` → belongs to many → `Role` → belongs to many → `Permission`

```
class User extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            'App\Permission',
            ['role_user', 'App\Role', 'permission_role'], // Pivot tables/models starting from the Parent, which is the User
        );
    }
}
```

Example if foreign keys need to be defined:

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep/issues/7#issuecomment-431477943