# Convert query in eloquent relationship laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have 5 tables `students`,`teachers`,`subjects`,`student_subject`,`subject_teacher`
student have many to many relationship with subject similarly teacher have many to many relation with subject .

students table

```
id | name | email
```

teachers table

```
id | name | email
```

subjects table

```
id | name
```

subject_teacher table:

```
id | teacher_id | subject_id
```

student_subject table:

```
id | student_id | subject_id
```

above is my database structure In models of `Student,Teacher,Subject` i define many to many relation.
So if i want to get subject of teacher i simply do `Teacher::find(1)->subjects()->get()`. In my current database structure i have not direct relation between students and teachers but i want to get all students of teacher i can do this with query like

```
 Student::join('student_subject', 'students.id', '=', 'student_subject.student_id')
 ->join('subject_teacher', 'student_subject.subject_id', '=', 'subject_teacher.subject_id')
 ->where('subject_teacher.teacher_id', '=',1)
  ->groupBy('students.name');
```

My problem i don't want query i want to do this with eloquent what i do what i will change in my relationship please help me

**Note**: I don't want to change in my database structure. I know if it is possible with query then it will surely possible with eloquent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HasManyThrough with one-to-many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788844/hasmanythrough-with-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: Not solving my problem

Comment: You want a has many through relationship but you can't have that because your relationships are all many to many

Comment: Can you give me example of has many through relation?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: I read that but in my case i have pivot table so how i can apply has many through relation in pivot table ??

Comment: You can't, that's not possible

Comment: So how can i solved my problem??

Comment: As far as I know there's no way that you can solve this using eloquent, the only thing that you might do is eager loading a nested relationship and then iterate for each subject and then iterate again for eahc teacher, something like `Student::with('subject.teacher')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your table's strtucture to use `Eloquent`. All you need is to create Eloquent models and defime relationships. So, let's create Models for `students`, `teachers` and `subjects` at first.

**Student Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model {

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class);
    }

}
```

**Teacher Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Teacher extends Model {

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class);
    }

}
```

**Subject Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subject extends Model {

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function teachers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
    }

}
```

Now you can use something like this:

```
// Get all students with related subjects
$studentsWithSubjects = \App\Student::with('subjects')->get();

// Get student with id 1 with related subjects
$student1WithSubjects = \App\Student::with('subjects')->find(1);
```

Use same rules with `Teacher` model. Hope it helps to get you started.

### Update:

Well, if you want to make a relation between `Teacher` & `Student` model using a `many-to-many` relationship then you need to create another pivot table using `id`, 'student_id' and `teacher_id` and then define relationship methods in both `Teacher` and `Student` model so you can use relationship method from both sides, for example:

```
// In Student Model
public function teachers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
}

// In Teacher Model
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
}
```

So now you'll be able to use something like this:

```
$teacher1WithStudents = \App\Teacher::with('students')->find(1);
$student1WithTeachers = \App\Student::with('teachers')->find(1);
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my prolem . I do the same thing with my model that you mentiond .  I can easily get student subject and teacher subject but i want to get student->teacher or teacher->student . I don't know what i do . If you know please help me

Answer (score 0):

I want to re-construct the question first:

There are teachers giving classes on some subjects. 
There are students taking classes on some subjects.

A student's teachers are the teachers giving classes on the subjects student taking.

A teacher's students are the students taking classes on the subjects teacher giving.

If that is correct I suggest you to use eager loading.

As an example, to get the student with id 1:

```
$student = App\Students::with(['subjects.teachers'])->find(1)->get();
```

Then you can do a foreach on

```
$student->subjects
```

And every subject will get teachers.

> **Attention! If you have just one subject for each teacher, use belongs to and has many relations.**

When you get the general idea about eager loading, you can use some other query constraints on the eager loading query to get directly what you want.

Check the eager loading section here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations