# Laravel 5.6: Car has many colours has many images. When trying to find all "red" images for car 1, I get red images for all cars

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database, eager-loading

I have three Models:

`Car.php`, `Colour.php`, `Image.php`.

They have the following relationships:

`Car belongsToMany Colour`: Because a car can have multiple colours.

`Colour belongsToMany Car`: Because a colour can appear on many cars.

`Car belongsToMany Image`: Because a car can have multiple images.

`Image belongsToMany Car`: Because one image can be used by multiple Cars.

`Image belongsTo Colour`: Because every image must have a colour.

`Colour hasMany Image`: Because the colour Red can be found in many images.

If I write `Car::find(1)->load('colours.images);` it returns all associated colours as expected, however each colour has *every* image that uses that colour. So I'll see Car 1, 2, 3 etc for Red instead of just the images for car 1.

It seems like the `colours.images` ignores the initial car.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like Car::find($id)->with(['colours.images' => function ($query) { $query->where('car_id', $id); }])

Comment: `with` before the `find`

Comment: The relationship between Colour and Image doesn't use car_id, so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation, but the problem is that your cars, colors and images are in many-to-many relationship (hasManyThrough only works with one-to-many relationship nesting).

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23789210/9348748) for more info and possible workaround.